# Ignore SuspiciousFileOperation in Django

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, whitenoise

I am serving my vuejs SPA in django at `/app/`

Serving static files at `/static/`

My app is working fine served in django development, but, collectstatic fails.

My vue.config.js has:

```
module.exports = {
    assetsDir: 'static',
}
```

Compiled CSS files have font urls like this:

```
url(../../static/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ee2bb9f3.eot
```

This works in the browser because it can't go up 2 dirs but in the filesystem goes up 2 dirs instead of one.

Works fine in the browser, but can't be deployed. It throws `SuspiciousFileOperation` exceptions:

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/mnt/c/Users/static/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ee2bb9f3.eot) is located outside of the base path component (/mnt/c/Users/fede_/braced/staticfiles)
```

I am really stuck with this.

Comment: Why are you prefixing the path with `../`?

Comment: I had `publicPath: '/app/'` too.
Now, I have the same issue with `publicPath:'/'` and `assetsDir: 'static'`.
It's maybe a problem with webpack. The compiled css has font routes like this: `url(../../static/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ee2bb9f3.eot`. Even without `../` in `assetsDir`. This works in development but collectstatic goes up two dirs instead of one.